# mouse wheel scrolling work with f5 in app but don't work on web

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Good day!
I have a web application on Silverlight 3.
on ManePage I have a

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="sV" MouseWheel="sV_MouseWheel" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

with such code:

```
private void sV_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            var offset = sV.VerticalOffset;
            sV.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset + (e.Delta * -0.5));
        }
```

When I press F5 button to debug my application,  mouse wheel scrolling works well, but when I press F6 and then choose Web.Project prperty Debug->Start New Instance or publish my project on site, mouse wheel scrolling doesn't work :(

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

oh, it works in IE, but doesn't work in other browsers